# Keeping character/factor variables when taking the mean of a dataset

Tags: r, string, type-conversion, mean, factors

I have a large dataset of which the following is a sample:

```
# A tibble: 450 x 546
   matchcode idstd year  country wt    region income industry sector ownership exporter c201  c202  c203a c203b c203c c203d c2041 c2042 c205a c205b1 c205b2 c205b3 c205b4 c205b5 c205b6 c205b7 c205b8 c205b9 c205b10 c205c c205d c206a c206b c2071
   <int+lbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int+l> <dbl> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+lb> <dbl+> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lb> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+> <dbl+l> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 "BGD 200~  2474 2002  Bangla~ 0.9    6      1       3       1      2         1        1994  2     100   0      0    NA     2    NA     NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       1     2    NA    NA    1    
 2 "BGD 200~  2717 2002  Bangla~ 1.2    6      1       2       1      2         2        1986  4     100   0      0    NA     2    NA     NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       1     1     2     2    2    
 3 "BGD 200~  2410 2002  Bangla~ 0.8    6      1       3       1      2         1        1999  4     100   0      0    NA     2    NA     NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       2    NA    NA    NA    1    
 4 "BRA 200~ 14917 2003  Brazil~ NA    4      2       8       1      2         2        1984  2     100   0      0     0     2    NA     50    1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1       1     1     1     2    3    
 5 "BRA 200~ 14546 2003  Brazil~ NA    4      2       2       1      2         2        1976  2     100   0      0     0     2    NA     50    1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1       1     1     1     2    4    
 6 "BRA 200~ 14709 2003  Brazil~ NA    4      2       3       1      2         2        1990  2     100   0      0     0     2    NA    100   NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       1     1     1     2    4    
 7 "KHM 200~ 16475 2003  Cambod~ NA    2      1      20       2      2         2        1999  2     100   0      0     0     2    NA    100   NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA    NA     1     2    1    
 8 "KHM 200~ 16298 2003  Cambod~ NA    2      1       4       3      2         2        1993  4     100   0      0     0     2    NA    100    1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       1     2     1     2    4    
 9 "KHM 200~ 16036 2003  Cambod~ 1.2    2      1      21       2      2         2        1997  2     100   0      0     0     2    NA    100   NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       1     1     1     2    1    
10 "CHN 200~ 17862 2002  China2~ 1.1    2      2      18       2      2         2        1993  3      49   0     51    NA    NA    NA     NA   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    2
```

which I summarised by using the following data table solution:

```
dfclevel= df[, lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, wt, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols, by=matchcode]
```

In this operation 7 factor variables, representing strings, are dropped, because obviously there is no weighted mean of a country name. However, since I take the mean by `matchcode` which is a combination of year and country, the information from those variables which have been dropped would still make sense (they should be identical for every matchcode) and for this and other reasons, I would like to keep these columns.

So the big question is, how do I do this? Can I temporarily convert these factors to numeric values and convert them back after applying the weighted mean across the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by sub setting the factors and taking a sample of those factors by `matchcode`. This leads to the desired result because, as explained in the original post, there is no variation in the factor columns per `matchcode`

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
is.fact <- sapply(df, is.factor)
dffactors <- df[, is.fact]
dffactors <- data.table(dffactors)
df <- data.table(df)
dffactors <- dffactors[,.SD[sample(.N, min(1,.N))],by = matchcode]
```

I then took the mean of the original df:

```
dfclevel= df[, lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, wt, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols, by=matchcode]
```

And merged the sample with `dfclevel`

```
dfclevel <- merge(dfclevel , dffactors,  by= "matchcode", all.x = TRUE, allow.cartesian=FALSE)
```